# Do you have an example of forced losing lines when you play the obvious move?

Tags: opening, opening-traps

I teach my students that the obvious move isn't always the right one.
Whenever I need to explain this in-depth, I show the Queen Amadala trap from the QGD (see below).

Obviously, a more talented student then asks for other examples and I'm out of ideas...

So the question is: **does anyone else know an opening sequence where the obvious (human) move is wrong?**

```
[FEN ""]
1.d4 d5 
2.c4 e6 
3.Nc3 Nf6 
4.Bg5 Nbd7 {seems to lose a pawn after exchanging?}
5.cxd5 exd5
6.Nxd5 {the pinned Knight gives away a pawn! Or doesn't it?} (6.e3 {is a more correct approach, but not the intention of the diagram.} c6 {and black seems a little defensive but life goes on.}) Nxd5 {seems to blunder a Q?}
7.Bxd8 Bb4+ {reclaims the Q and eventually gains a Bishop.}
```

Comment: This can be generated automatically with a program. But you can also find these type of positions by searching the internet with `chess opening traps` or just `chess traps` string.

Comment: I understand the fact you can use machine analysed chess traps etc. But I am looking for a more human approach. e.g. the Copycat variation `1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nxe5 Nxe4 4. Qe2 Nf6 5. Nc6+` is a well known trap in the Petrov, which you can easily find. It's a bit a foolish trap with consequences if the adversary 'doesn't bite' however. So I'm looking for something that is still playable if they don't fall for the 'trap'.